# How to include a document made with Rmd into an HTML page

Tags: html, r

I'm making an interactive document with Rmd (ggplot and some text) and need to include it into my website.

Can I export an HTML file from R only like a div tag and not like a full file with a head, body etc?

or should I export a full HTML file and create an iframe?

Comment: You can get a HTML fragment. Try `render("yourfile.Rmd", output_format = html_fragment())` after loading the `rmardown` package.

Comment: It doesn't seem to work for interactive plots, I tried using ggiraph and kable and it doesn't render the plots. Does it mean I can't use these extensions in HTML fragments?

Comment: Do you want the plots to be interactive in your website? If so, you need to use `shiny`

Comment: I would still need to embed the app in an iframe right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using `<object>` and it works well.